# save memory when updating billion records with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

I have an collection with billion records. I need to update all records every 5 minutes. It will consume a lot of memory if I query all records then update every record by loop. Does mongoose/node-mongodb-native support to update every record one by one. 
My logic is get one record, do some calculation on that record, then save back to database.

Comment: The solution depends on if this update can be done directly on the mongoDB server?

Comment: yes, directly on the mongoDB server